# dataSource.getConnection() cannot get the connection

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

i have one project,it's use Spring Framework and use `org.apache.commons.dbc` to connect the database (ms-sql), when i execute to this line

```
jdbcTemplate.execute(sql,new CallableStatementCallback(){
        public Object doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs)
                throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

then, my program can not go to the next line and no exception or error id thrown out,
and finally the console print this:

```
 AbandonedObjectPool is used (org.apache.commons.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool@1a2467a)` 
 LogAbandoned: false
 RemoveAbandoned: true
 RemoveAbandonedTimeout: 180
```

but the program is not stop, it's just like be stuck and i try to trace where it's wrong , finally I got this line in `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils` class:

```
Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
```

my datasource is right,because i create another project to ensure there is no problem with xml file,and datasource is not null and the process is stuck at

```
BasicDataSource.createDataSource() line： 1221
```

I'm confused, what is wrong or what might wrong?

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: OP said there is "no exception or error id thrown out", so there probably isn't an exception ...

Comment: Try executing the program in a debugger, and suspend the thread once its stuck. You will then have a stack trace of where it is stuck, which ought to be revealing.

Comment: @meriton yes，i did this before i ask for help,i got a stack trace `BasicDataSource.createDataSource() line： 1221`,this is maybe the connect problem,but when i use the same connect in other project it worked,so i am confused

Comment: A stack trace contains more than one line. What are the other lines? (Are you sure they are not relevant to the problem ...?)

Comment: sorry,i made a stupid mistake,i used the wrong jdk,thanks for your help and patience anyway